# Printing crystal reports from a web service to a network printer

Tags: c#, web-services

We have handheld scanners in a big warehouse, and there are printers scattered around the warehouse. When certain events happen on the scanner I need to Print a Crystal report to a printer.

The scanner sends everything through a web service.

Currently I have the web service printing the document and it is working (kinda), but I want to move the printing functionality out of the web service (a few reasons).

I am not sure if I should create a console app or some other type of application to handle the printing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I guess I am looking for a high level spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have control of the system's behavior as the scanner interacts with the web service.  If so, and you want to decouple printing the document from the web service, have you considered using a message queue?

I'm thinking when the event in question occurs at the web service, drop a message into the queue with all the specifics.  Then create an application that can either by triggered by the queue, or monitor the queue for outstanding requests, and have it print the document.

Comment: Thank you. looks like a [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) would work, and be fairly easy to implement.